# STM32 hardware device date type and DSP library data type, conversion load price

Tags: signal-processing, stm32, fixed-point

I am working on a project based on STM32 which acquires signals, processes them and send them to serial link. I want to use the [STM32 DSP library using CMSIS](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00273990-digital-signal-processing-for-stm32-microcontrollers-using-cmsis-stmicroelectronics.pdf) to process signals in real time.

- My ADC (16bits) and DFSDM (24bits), with the help of DMA, give me **uint16** or **int32** buffer containing the data of my sensors.
- The functions of DSP library waiting for fixed point data types **float**, **q31** or **q15**.

So naively, I think I need to convert and normalize my buffer of samples to be able to use the DSP library, and then, after processing signals I need to denormalize and convert data again to retrieve my **uint16** and **int32** samples types.

This imply two loop over the whole buffer just for conversion, this seem a crazy heavy load even before having done any treatment ...

I have the impression of having missed something to efficiently use the DSP library without lost to much time into conversion process.

Can someone help me to change my mind ?

Comment: what is the range that is represented by the values stored in the input? If it is [-1..1) then you may find that it is already in the correct format.

Comment: Ho, yes sorry I dont speak about range. The DFSDM is 24bits (stored in int32) and the ADC is 16bits (stored in uint16).

Comment: what range do those numbers represent? Do you know how many of the bits of the input integers are meant to be integer bits and how many are fractional bits? Are they normalised to unit range, (i.e. values no greater than one)?